# How do I create a link in a table that reveals my search results from a count?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have two sets of data, one for Clients and one for the Vacancies of the clients. So In my table I have successfully created a button which when clicked displays Client results, this includes a ClientID and a Client Name. I have also linked in some Vacancy details where I manage to to tally the amount of vacancies they have in relation to the client. Right now I would like to create a fourth table header which is populated with links that will bring the user to another page which displays those vacancies, instead of just tallying them up in another header. I will paste the code (except from the data) to see if this helps. This is my 8th day of coding with MVC and still find it confusing at time. If you dont want to write the code, it would be helpful if you could tell me if I need another controller, or more models. Thank you.

**View:**

```
 <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Reference </th>
                <th> Client Name </th>
                <th> Number of Vacancies per Client </th>
                <th> Link for the vacancies </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

    <%
        Dim oClient As VacancyManager2.DataModels.Client

        For Each oClient In Model.SearchResults
    %>
            <tr>
                <td><%: oClient.ClientID%></td>
                <td><%: oClient.ClientName%></td>
                <td><%: oClient.NumberOfVacancies%></td>
                <td><%: Html.ActionLink("The Number of Vacancies", "IndexSearchNumOfVacancies", "ClientSearch")%></td>
            </tr>
    <%
        Next
    %>
            </tbody>
```

**Controller:**

```
 <HttpGet()>
    Function IndexSearch() As ActionResult
        Dim oModel As ViewModels.ClientSearch = New ViewModels.ClientSearch
        oModel.SearchText = ""
        oModel.SearchResults = New List(Of DataModels.Client)

        Return View(oModel)
    End Function

<HttpPost()>
    Function IndexSearch(PostedInfo As FormCollection) As ActionResult
        Dim sClientName = PostedInfo("ClientName")
        Dim oModel As ViewModels.ClientSearch = New ViewModels.ClientSearch
        oModel.SearchText = sClientName
        Dim oClientList As DataModels.ClientList = New DataModels.ClientList
        oModel.SearchResults = oClientList.SearchClients(sClientName)
        Return View(oModel)


    End Function
```

**DataModel:**

```
Public Class Client
        Property ClientID As Integer
        Property ClientName As String

Public Sub New(inClientID As Integer, inClientName As String)
            Me.ClientID = inCLientID
            Me.ClientName = inClientName
        End Sub

Function NumberOfVacancies() As Integer
            Dim oVacancyList As VacancyList = New VacancyList
            Return oVacancyList.NumberOfVacancies(Me.ClientID)
        End Function
    End Class

Function SearchClients(inSearchFor As String) As List(Of Client)

            Dim oResults As List(Of Client) = New List(Of Client)
            Dim oClient As DataModels.Client
            For Each oClient In Me.Clients
                If LCase(oClient.ClientName).Contains(LCase(inSearchFor)) Then
                    oResults.Add(oClient)
                End If
            Next

            Return oResults
        End Function

Function ClientName(inClientID As Integer) As String
            Dim sClientName As String = ""

            Dim oClient As DataModels.Client
            For Each oClient In Me.Clients
                If oClient.ClientID = inClientID Then
                    sClientName = oClient.ClientName
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            Return sClientName
        End Function
```

**ViewModel:**

```
Public Class ClientSearch
        Property SearchText As String
        Property SearchResults As List(Of DataModels.Client)
    End Class
```

Comment: You would need an action method that accepts the `clientID` as a parameter, (say `Function VacancyDetails(ID As Integer) As ActionResult`) which returns a view for the clients vacancy details. Then the action link would be `Html.ActionLink("Vacancy details", "VacancyDetails", "YourController", new { id = Client.ClientID }, Nothing)`.

Comment: Thank you, how would the function go? Would I need a Get and Post function?

Comment: If you only want to display the vacancy detail for each client, then just a GET method.